# Counting the occurence and printing summary of that

Tags: gvim

I want to sumarize data information as output shown. My data look like this:

```
apple 
orange{1}
orange{2}
...
orange{600}
mango{1}
mango{2}
...
mango{600}
strawberry
blueberry
```

I want output summary like this:

```
apple = 1
orange = 600
mango = 600
strawberry = 1
blueberry = 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Completely off topic but I think that should be "blueberry" unless it's the name of a person.

Comment: I want to uniqf the name but it has number ending So how to do that. Also i want to count the uniqfied name.

Comment: I suggest you trying a python 10-liner.

Comment: can i grep for only string in line and then uniqfy it ?IF  yes then how to grep only the string (alphabets) in the file.

Comment: i was able to gerp only alphabets grep -oi '[a-z]*' | uniq . Only now the issue is how to calculate the uniquified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done interactively in a non optimized way.

Ideally, this should be wrapped in a function, `matchstr` call could be optimized...

```
:let c = {}
:g/.*/let g:c[matchstr(getline('.'), '^[^ {=]*')] = get(g:c, matchstr(getline('.'), '^[^ {=]*'), 0) +1

:echo c
" or
:call append('.', c->items()->map({ k, v -> printf("%s = %d", v[0], v[1])}))
```

Another way (better starting point when we want to write a function we'll reuse several times)

```
:let words = getline(1, '$')->map({_, v -> matchstr(v, '^\k\+')})->filter({_,v -> len(v)})
:let c = {}
:call map(copy(words), { _, v -> extend(g:c, {v: get(g:c, v, 0) + 1})})
:call append('.', c->items()->map({ k, v -> printf("%s = %d", v[0], v[1])}))
```

or, from bash (as you've already found...):

```bash
cat file | grep -io '[a-z]*' | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oi '[a-z]*' <file> | uniq -c
```

First tried to grep all the alphabet:

```
grep -oi '[a-z]*'
```

Where:

- `-o, --only-matching`
- `-i, --ignore-case`

then "uniqify" and got the number of uniq occurrence
Where:

- `-c, --count`

Comment: What does this have to do with Vim?

Comment: i needed to do this in gvim . My bad if i asked question in wrong place . But thanks i got the answer.